# IDE Problem ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android

Tags: arcgis-android, arcgis-runtime, sdk, eclipse, intellij-idea

I'm trying to develop an app with ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android. Honestly, I'm not much experienced.

Just looking for the best IDE choise.

Eclipse works just fine with the Runtime SDK. But has no library documentation in the IDE.
[image: How Runtime SDK Docs is seen in Eclipse]

IntelliJ IDEA 12+ is a good option for Android Development. But I couldn't use the Runtime SDK (v10.1.1) in it.

I want to import [the documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/android-sdk/api/reference/com/esri/core/tasks/ags/query/Query.html) to the one of these IDEs. Such as : 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do have IDE choices. But the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android comes with a terrific Eclipse plugin, and works very well. The plugin does include the API reference, which right now is broken when you hit F1 key as you mentioned. It also includes integrated conceptual help, project templates and tools, integrated samples, etc.

IntelliJ can be configured to use the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android SDK. Check out [this blog post](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/10/26/developing-with-the-arcgis-runtime-sdk-for-android-and-intellij-idea/).

Comment: thank you for the answer. actually, I couldn't use IntelliJ IDEA with the new version of the SDK (v.10.1.1). But [this post](http://www.gisharp.com/using-arcgis-runtime-sdk-for-android-in-intellij-idea/) was pretty helpful.

The tip about F1 was great...

Answer (score 0):

The [update to ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android v10.1.1-u1](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/android/) has the fix for javadoc hover in Eclipse.  The next release of the SDK will have improved support for alternative IDE's but please be more specific as to why you cannot use IntelliJ with this version of the SDK as I am sure we can address your issues.

Comment: With this update, Eclipse is terrific about documentation. Developing with pleasure :)